# Transferring large amounts of data over bluetooth on Android Gingerbread

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to transfer about a megabyte of arbitrary data at a time from one android phone to another. Currently, I write the size, a command code and the data to a `DataOutputStream` around a `BufferedOutputStream`, around the `OutputStream` returned from `bluetoothSocketInstance.getOutputStream()`.

The receiving phone reads the size and command code and then reads from the input stream until it has gotten all the data it is expecting. This works for short strings, but for larger files not all the data is transferred. Running the app in the debugger shows that the write returns without any exceptions and the read reads a fraction of the bytes expected and then blocks indefinitely. It also does not throw any exceptions.

Is there a buffer somewhere that is filling up? Is there something else I need to do to ensure that all the data gets transferred?

My code for the sender and receiver are below:

Sender:

```
  try {

            DataOutputStream d = new DataOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(mmOutStream,buffer.length+8));
            //int b= buffer.length;
            d.writeInt(buffer.length);
            d.writeInt(command);

            d.write(buffer);
            d.flush();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception during write", e);
        }
    }
```

Receiver:

```
 try {

                // Read from the InputStream
                int messageSize= inStream.readInt();
                int messageCode = inStream.readInt();
                bytes=0;
                buffer =new byte[messageSize];
                while(bytes < messageSize)
                {
                    bytes += inStream.read(buffer,bytes,messageSize - bytes);

                }
                    message = bytes;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                connectionLost();
                break;
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more testing on my end, I changed my sending code to look like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<buffer.length;i+=BIG_NUM)
            {
                int b = ((i+BIG_NUM) < buffer.length) ? BIG_NUM: buffer.length - i;
                d.write(buffer,i,b);
                d.flush();
            }
```

The files now get sent. Does anyone have an idea why? Does the call to `flush()` block until the data has actually been transferred? Is there any documentation about the size of the send and receive buffers that would help me to decide how large I can safely make `BIG_NUM`?

Comment: The bluetooth send buffer is 70 KiB in the BluetoothSocket native code (in my copy). Also, Linux doubles this internally (because of "kernel data structures"). However, this should not be a problem since `write(3)` should manage this. Also, flush may do nothing (because write seems to be synchronous) and it (flush) is not overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, when sending file there are some parts missing. I try BufferedOutputStream but problem still exist.

Finally i find simple solution:

You don't need to send buffer length, just split sending buffer to byte array (for example [8192]) and on receive side make sure that this buffer is much bigger about 4 or 8 times than sending buffer. This worked for me and file is sent completed.

Comment: That's similar to how I wound up solving the problem. Do you know what the maximum size of the sending buffer can be before I split it up?